# Explicit loading libraries in MonacoEditor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use MonacoEditor for editing JS scripts in my own environment, that will be executed by GraalVM Truffle.

There is need to import one script module into another, so is right way to use import statement, but i can find examples, when library content injected implicit

```
var libSource = [
    'declare class Facts {',
    '    /**',
    '     * Returns the next fact',
    '     */',
    '    static next():string',
    '}'
].join('\n');
var libUri = 'ts:filename/facts.d.ts';
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(libSource, libUri);
// When resolving definitions and references, the editor will try to use created models.
// Creating a model for the library allows "peek definition/references" commands to work with the library.
monaco.editor.createModel(libSource, 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse(libUri));
```

But i need to load library's content explicit, something like following pseudo code

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.<getLibraryWorker>().then(worker => {
    worker.<onImportLibrary>(uri => fetch('http://mylibrary.storage.uri');
});
```

PS Also it will be acceptable to set some URI to recieve scripts from web-server

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creation feature request on github
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3528
[tamayika](https://github.com/tamayika) suggest using code from Typescript-Website project. But it is hardcoded to use site https://data.jsdelivr.com, that was unapplicable for me.

So i simplified this approach and got following code

```
import {Uri} from 'monaco-editor';
import {preProcessFile} from 'file_preparer'
type MonacoContentLoaderOptions = {
baseUrl:string
}

type ModuleInfo = {
    uri: Uri,
    state: 'loading' | 'ready'
}

class MonacoContentLoader {

    _baseUrl: string;
    _dependencyMap: Map<string, ModuleInfo>;

    constructor(props: MonacoContentLoaderOptions) {
        this._baseUrl = props.baseUrl;
        this._dependencyMap = new Map<string, ModuleInfo>();
    }

    async resolveDependencies(sourceFile) {
        await this.resolveDeps(sourceFile, 0);
    }

    async resolveDeps(initialSourceFile: string, depth: number) {
        const me = this;
        let dependencies = me.getNewDependencies(initialSourceFile).filter(dep => !me._dependencyMap.has(dep))
        dependencies.forEach(dep => me._dependencyMap.set(dep, {
            uri: Uri.parse(dep + ".js"),
            state: 'loading'
        }))
        await Promise.all(
            dependencies.map(async module => {
                let moduleInfo = me._dependencyMap.get(module);
                let content = await me.getContent(module);
                if (monaco.editor.getModel(moduleInfo.uri) === null) {
                    monaco.editor.createModel(content, "javascript", moduleInfo.uri);
                }
                moduleInfo.state = 'ready';
                await me.resolveDeps(content, depth + 1);
            })
        )
    }

    getNewDependencies(content: string) {
        const me = this;
        const refs = me.getReferencesForModule(content);

        return refs.filter(f => !f.startsWith(".")).filter(m => !me._dependencyMap.has(m))
    }

    getReferencesForModule(content: string): string[] {
        const meta = preProcessFile(content)
        const libMap = new Map<string, string>()

        const references = meta.referencedFiles
            .concat(meta.importedFiles)
            .concat(meta.libReferenceDirectives)
            .filter(f => !f.fileName.endsWith(".d.ts"))
            .filter(d => !libMap.has(d.fileName))

        return references.map(r => {
            return r.fileName;
        })
    }

    async getContent(moduleName: string): Promise<string> {
        const me = this;
        const request = new Request(me._baseUrl + moduleName, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/html"
            }
        });
        const response = await fetch(request);
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.text();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unable to resolve ${moduleName}`);
        }
    }
}
```

After it we can create singleton (because monaco.editor.getModels is singleton)

```
const loader = new MonacoContentLoader('http://my.content.endpoint.com');
```

Then, when we are creating editor, we should to use monaco-model

```
 let editor = monaco.editor.create(me.bodyPanel.body.dom, {
            model: model,
            automaticLayout: true
        });
        editor.getModel().onDidChangeContent(() => {
            clearTimeout(me.processContent);
me.processContent = setTimeout(()=> 
loader.resolveDependencies(editor.getValue())
        ,1000});
```

So this code provides processing js/ts code and resolve imports